# Problem making comparison on item in \clist added from itself

Tags: expl3

Could someone please explain to me what's going on here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_mjc_a_clist
\clist_new:N \l_mjc_b_clist

\clist_set:Nn \l_mjc_a_clist { a }
\clist_put_right:Nn \l_mjc_a_clist { \clist_item:Nn \l_mjc_a_clist { 1 } }
\str_if_eq:eeTF { \clist_item:Nn \l_mjc_a_clist { 2 } } { a } { 1 } { 0 } \hspace{1em} % returns 0

\clist_set:Nn \l_mjc_b_clist { b } 
\clist_put_right:Nn \l_mjc_b_clist { b }
\str_if_eq:eeTF { \clist_item:Nn \l_mjc_b_clist { 2 } } { b } { 1 } { 0 } % returns 1

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you please name your variables correctly? That should be e.g. `\l_mjc_a_clist`. It makes your code more readable if you follow naming conventions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to add to the clist the tokens

```
\clist_item:Nn \l_mjc_a_clist { 1 }
```

but the item. You accomplish this by using `\clist_put_right:Nx`, so `\clist_item:Nn` is expanded. Look at the technical note in the description to see that expansion only goes up to providing the actual item and not further.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_mjc_a_clist
\clist_new:N \l_mjc_b_clist

\clist_set:Nn \l_mjc_a_clist { a }
\clist_put_right:Nx \l_mjc_a_clist { \clist_item:Nn \l_mjc_a_clist { 1 } }
\str_if_eq:eeTF { \clist_item:Nn \l_mjc_a_clist { 2 } } { a } { 1 } { 0 }

\par\bigskip

\clist_set:Nn \l_mjc_b_clist { b }
\clist_put_right:Nn \l_mjc_b_clist { b }
\str_if_eq:eeTF { \clist_item:Nn \l_mjc_b_clist { 2 } } { b } { 1 } { 0 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `\clist_show:N \l_mjc_a_clist`:

```
The comma list \l_mjc_a_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {a}
>  {\clist_item:Nn \l_mjc_a_clist {1}}.
<recently read> }
```

so your second item is not what you thought it is. You need `\clist_put_right:Ne` and as that doesn't exist (I think) probably `\exp_args:NNe\clist_put_right:Nn`

Comment: `\clist_put_right:Nx`